# Saber el número de días del mes anterior

Tags: java

Necesito implementar una forma de saber los días que tiene el mes anterior a la fecha actual cuando es día 1. El código que tengo ahora mismo es el siguiente.

```
Calendar fechaActual = new GregorianCalendar();

if(fechaActual.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)==1) {

}
```

La idea es multiplicar el número de días del mes anterior por una variable dentro del if. El problema es que no sé como restarle 1 día a `fechaActual` para que cambie de mes. Se me ha ocurrido hacerlo de manera manual definiendo el número de días que tiene cada mes. La cosa es que estoy seguro de que tiene que haber algún método para hacerlo de forma mucho más rápida pero no doy con él.

Comment: la cantidad de dias del mes anterior se calcula como el ir al primer dia del mes actual, usar el mes y año actual para generar el calendario, y luego de eso restarle un dia, y fijarte el valor de day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para calcular el número de días del mes anterior puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```java
LocalDate fechaActual= LocalDate.now();

//Colocamos la fecha actual en el primer dia del mes
fechaActual= fechaActual.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth());

//A la fecha actual que se encuentra en el primer día del mes le restamos un día 
//lo que nos coloca en el mes anterior
LocalDate mesAnterior = fechaActual.minusDays(1);

//Capturamos el numero de dias del mes
int numeroDias= mesAnterior.lengthOfMonth();
```

***Nota***

*Esta solución solo funciona a parir de la versión java 8 en adelante*

Comment: si es enero, mes no da 0? y luego el set de month falla?

Comment: tienes razón lo acabo de probar, voy a reestructurar la respuesta con una mejor solución

Answer (score 3):

Te doy dos variantes. La primera, si bien funciona perfectamente con la última versión de Java, es un poco el estilo antiguo de trabajar con fechas. La segunda variante funciona con la nueva Date/Time API introducida en Java 8.

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
System.out.println(calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

// Solo funciona a partir de Java 8
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
System.out.println(date.minusMonths(1).lengthOfMonth());
```